# Which visa can I apply for USA for file a divorce case?

Tags: usa

My H4 visa is expired and my hubby is not sending my visa papers . he is forcing me for divorce.  right now i am living in India. I want to go USA and file my case. Can I apply a tourist visa and go USA to file my case. 
Someone said to me Make My Trip organize a USA tour. Is this a good option , I should go USA on a tour and then stay there and file my case.
Please give me the advise.

Comment: Ask your consulate. Not only for visa, but also for what do you need for the divorce case.

Comment: Honestly, you should find a reputable divorce attorney in the United States to represent you and to protect your rights. If your physical presence is required, you can make arrangements at that time.

Comment: if by "stay there" you mean overstaying your visa: don't. Next, anyone can turn to a court of law, citizens, residents, visitors, undocumented aliens, anyone. You need  to but also can file for a divorce in the state where your husband lives -- as far as I am aware, but I am not a lawyer, the residency / domicile requirement can be satisfied by just one party. Lawyering up as @ZachLipton suggests is certainly a good idea since the time limitations of your visa makes personal representation difficult.

Comment: Stay there mean...if I got a tourist visa and then I live in California and file my case

Comment: I lived in USA 12 years on H4 visa. Is this a positive thing to apply Tourist visa

Comment: Thnx all for ur suggestion

Comment: Before you could file for a divorce in California, you would have to live there for 6 months, so it would be difficult, if not impossible for you to do so as a tourist and file. If your husband files there, then you will have 30 days to answer after being served with the petition. After that, it takes another 6 months for it to be finalized. Per @ZachLipton, consult an attorney first.

Comment: @Dorothy I'm seeing 2 alternatives. Either spouse can fulfill the residency rule (which must include 3 months within county where you're filing). The other alternate is to file for a legal separation or to annul the marriage but there are only a few acceptable reasons for an annulment.

Comment: @mkennedy agreed, and that sounds as though what the husband is doing if he is still in CA as an H1.. It would be very risky for OP to use a tourist visa to do so, as it is non-immigrant and doesn't cover residency. It sounds as though OP does want the divorce but, after living in the US for 12 years, actually wants to continue to reside here. Better that she consults with an attorney, for both divorce and immigration.

Answer (score 3):

While there is no direct confirmation anymore (the US embassy in Philippines [used to say](https://web.archive.org/web/20160716093624/http://manila.usembassy.gov/wwwhniv7.html) that B1 is an appropriate visa to "appear in a court trial" but they redesigned the page), it still seems that B1 is the only appropriate visa in your case.

However before doing so, you need to think whether you need to go there yourself, or hire an attorney instead. California is a "no-fault divorce" state. This means - in my non-legal understanding - that the court doesn't bother finding out about why are you really divorcing, and whose fault it is - nor the "fault" is taken into account when property is being divided. Thus the process is less formal, and [you're not even required to go to court](http://www.courts.ca.gov/1226.htm). Usually hiring the attorney makes sense if you have children (in this case the divorce would have to go through the court), or if you have property worth fighting for, and cannot agree on how it should be divided.

Also if you hire an attorney, the attorney might be able to do the processing without requiring you to be physically present.